# How to get generic type definition for CRTP type

Tags: reflection, f#, crtp

Given the following [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) type in C#:

```
public abstract class DataProviderBase<TProvider>
    where TProvider : DataProviderBase<TProvider> { }
```

How would I get its generic type definition in F#?

```
let typeDef = typedefof<DataProviderBase<_>>
```

yields the error:

> Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'DataProviderBase<'a>' for a type inference variable. The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and 'DataProviderBase<'a>' Consider adding further type constraints

In C#, it would be:

```
var typeDef = typeof(DataProviderBase<>);
```

#### UPDATE

I found a workaround:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type DummyProvider() =
  inherit DataProviderBase<DummyProvider>()

let typeDef = typeof<DummyProvider>.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

Is there another way to do it, without the extra type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is actually a very good question. I didn't find a better workaround for this. 
You can slightly simplify your workaround by using `typedefof` like this:

```
let typeDef = typedefof<DataProviderBase<DummyProvider>>
```

**TECHNICAL DETAILS**

The problem is that F#'s `typedefof<'T>` is just an ordinary function that takes a type argument (unlike `typeof` in C#, which is an operator). In order to call it, you need to give it an actual type and the function will then call `GetGenericTypeDefinition` under the cover.

The reason why `typedefof<option<_>>` works is that F# specifies a *default* type as an argument (in this case `obj`). In general, F# chooses the less concrete type that matches the constraints. In your case:

`DataProviderBase<_>`   will become    `DataProviderBase<DataProviderBase<_>>` and so on.

Unless you define a new type (as in your workaround), there is no *concrete type* that could be used as a type argument of `typedefof<...>`. In this case, the defaulting mechanism simply doesn't work...

Comment: Any idea why the F# team chose to implement `typeof`/`typedefof` as functions? I like your simplification of the workaround.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't have an authoritative answer, but my guess is that they did that because they could. The `typeof` function uses some inline IL and the other is quite simple: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs. It works almost like C#'s operator (your example is the first one I know about where it fails), but doesn't require new syntax.

Comment: @Tomas, @Daniel - other constraints can also be problematic: consider `type T<'a when 'a : enum<int>>() = class end`, which has the same problem.

Comment: @kvb: In light of that, it seems kinda broken. Should it be submitted as a bug?

Comment: @Daniel - I sent in a bug report a few years ago...  I'll reraise the issue.