# f# Get generic type definition of type with constraints

Tags: generics, f#

here is the end goal: get a new connection from a factory by name like so `factory.CreateConnection<SqlConnection>("my db")`

Here is my code so far:

```
type IConnectionFactory =
    abstract member CreateConnection : unit -> IDbConnection

type DefaultConnectionFactory<'t when 't : (new : unit -> 't) and 't :> IDbConnection> () =
    member this.CreateConnection () = new 't()

    interface IConnectionFactory with
        member this.CreateConnection () = this.CreateConnection() :> IDbConnection

type DefaultConnectionFactoryFactory() =
    member this.CreateConnectionFactory connectionType =
        if not (typeof<IDbConnection>.IsAssignableFrom connectionType)
        then invalidArg "connectionType" (sprintf "type %O is not assignable to IDbConnection" connectionType)

        let genericFactoryType = typedefof<DefaultConnectionFactory<_>>
        let factorytype = genericFactoryType.MakeGenericType([| connectionType |])
        Activator.CreateInstance(factorytype) :?> IConnectionFactory

type ConnectionFactory (connectionStrings : Dictionary<string, (IConnectionFactory * string)>) =
    let ConnectionStrings = connectionStrings

    member this.CreateConnection connectionStringName : 't :> IDbConnection =
        if ConnectionStrings.ContainsKey connectionStringName
        then
            let connectionFactory, connectionString = ConnectionStrings.Item connectionStringName
            let connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection ()
            connection.ConnectionString <- connectionString
            connection :?> 't
        else invalidArg "dataSourceName" (sprintf "no data source found named %s" connectionStringName)
```

on this line :

```
let genericFactoryType = typedefof<DefaultConnectionFactory<_>>
```

I am getting this error:
Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'IDbConnection' for a type inference variable. A generic construct requires that the type 'IDbConnection' have a public default constructor Consider adding further type constraints

I'm not sure how to resolve it... Any other suggestions are welcome as well

Comment: `ConnectionFactoryFactory`?? ...how meta.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions if you think there is a better way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort of related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783284/how-to-get-generic-type-definition-for-crtp-type). The problem is `typedefof<DefaultConnectionFactory<_>>`. The constraint on `DefaultConnectionFactory` requires a type that implements `IDbConnection` and has a default constructor. The compiler knows of no such type. So, you'll have to provide one. You could use `SqlConnection`, for instance:

```
typedefof<DefaultConnectionFactory<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection>>
```

The effect is the same. `typedefof` will return the unbounded type `DefaultConnectionFactory<>` (in C# terms), which is impossible to express in F#.

Comment: yeah.... I found that worked but it seems kludgly, like I am missing something simple. I keep thinking there has to be a way to get the generic type definition without supplying a type. Thanks for the reference... I didn't see that when I searched.

Comment: F# doesn't provide a way of specifying an unbounded type. You can use a wildcard (as you have) if the constraints are trivial and it typically resolves to `obj`.